# RSPEC/Capybara not detecting fields

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

I'm having problems testing a Rails app with `capybara`.
I am trying to check that a post is created with a specific comment.
The issue is that `Capybara` is not recognising my fields.

```
3) posts index page adding posts invalid post shows an error
     Failure/Error: click_button 'Create Post'
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find button "Create Post"

4) Uploading photos displays image on post page
 Failure/Error: fill_in 'Description', with: 'My holiday pic'
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find field "Description"
```

## new.html.erb

```
<% if @post.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>

    <ul>
    <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= form_for @post, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :description %>
  <%= f.text_area :description %>

  <%= f.label :picture %>
  <%= f.file_field :picture %>

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

## Page source

```
<p class="notice"></p>
<p class="alert"></p>

<div class="container">

<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/posts" class="new_post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="new_post" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="TpeVS+Z1c4x5V+TRRXuGWYP0oLYi7fIlEU8S6f1ugwg=" /></div>
  <label for="post_description">Description</label>
  <textarea id="post_description" name="post[description]">
</textarea>

  <label for="post_picture">Picture</label>
  <input id="post_picture" name="post[picture]" type="file" />

  <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Create Post" />
</form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

## Specs

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'posts index page' do
  context 'no posts' do
    it 'shows a message' do
      visit '/posts'
      expect(page).to have_content 'No posts yet'
    end
  end

  describe 'adding posts' do
    context 'valid post' do
      it 'is added to the posts page' do
        visit '/posts/new'
        fill_in 'Description', with: 'My holiday pic'

        expect(current_path).to eq '/posts'
        expect(page).to have_content 'My holiday pic'
      end
    end

    describe 'deleting a post' do
      it 'removes the post' do
        visit '/posts'
        click_link 'Delete'

        expect(page).not_to have_content 'My holiday pic'
      end
    end

    context 'invalid post' do
      it 'shows an error' do
        visit '/posts/new'
        click_button 'Create Post'

        expect(page).to have_content 'error'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I found a similar solution in a related post that said to specify the `id`, such as `post_description` in the `new.html.erb`, but that had no effect.

Comment: I don't see any specs

Comment: It hard to tell exactly. But you can always use `save_and_open_page` after `visit` smt. and investigate if a button is in place

Comment: You can also retrieve the current state of the DOM as a string using `print page.html`

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
The problem was that because I had implemented user authentication in the application but not in the tests, this method was preventing the test from finding the fields that only a logged in user should be able to see.

## In posts_controller.rb

```
def new
  authenticate_user!
  @post = Post.new
end
```

Once a test user was implemented using Factory Girl gem the tests passed fine.